# Read XML files with powershell for-each loop

Tags: xml, powershell, for-loop

I am fairly new to powershell and I am wanting to read from multiple XML files which each have servers and services. These XML files vary in structure.

```
<application name="AutoCAD">
    <server name="server1">
        <services>
            <service name="Flexlm Service 1" />
        </services>
    </server>
    <server name="server2">
        <services>
            <service name="Flexlm Service 1" />
        </services>
    </server>
    <server name="server3">
        <services>
            <service name="Flexlm Service 1" />
        </services>
    </server>
</application>
```

I would like to read each XML file and pull out the server names along with the service I want to check whether it is running or not.

My current code is nearly working but it thinks there are 3 services for each server. I have tried a lot of things and now stuck.

```
$stopped = "ERROR"
$running = "RUNNING"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\rjohnso1\Desktop\Reports\XML" -Filter *.xml | 

Foreach-Object {
    $content = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    $servicesReport = @()
    $computer = $content.application.server.name
    $appName = $content.application.name
    $service = $content.application.server.services.service.name

    foreach ($computers in $computer){
        foreach ($services in $service){
            $serviceName = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service}
                if ($serviceName.State -eq 'Running'){
                    $row = "$($appName) $($computers) $($services) $($running) "
                }
                elseif ($serviceName.State -eq 'Stopped'){
                    $row = "$($appName) $($services) $($stopped) "
                    $error = "$($appName) $($service) "
                }
        $row += $servicesReport
        Write-Host $row
       }
    }
 }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Sorry Ryan - not really sure what your question is on this one! What's the problem with your current code? What isn't it doing that it should?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already populated `$service` with *all* the service nodes before the first loop in the xml document, you'll be looping through all of them for every server. Change it to:

```
$content = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)

$servicesReport = @()
$appName = $content.application.name

foreach ($computer in $content.application.server){
    foreach ($service in $computer.services.service){
        $serviceName = $service.Name
        Write-Host $serviceName
        $serviceInstance = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "DisplayName = '$serviceName'"}
        if ($serviceInstance.State -eq 'Running'){
            $row = "$($appName) $($computer) $($service) $($running) "
        }
        elseif ($serviceName.State -eq 'Stopped'){
            $row = "$($appName) $($service) $($stopped) "
            $error = "$($appName) $($service) "
        }
        $servicesReport += $row
        Write-Host $row
    }
}
```

Now, each `$row` being a single string is not very useful if the `$appName` or `$serviceName` has any spaces in it. To have it output structured data instead, create a bunch of objects instead:

```
$stopped = "ERROR"
$running = "RUNNING"

Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\rjohnso1\Desktop\Reports\XML" -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
    $content = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    $servicesReport = @()
    $appName = $content.application.name

    foreach ($computer in $content.application.server){
        foreach ($service in $computer.services.service){
            $serviceName = $service.name
            Write-Host $serviceName
            $serviceInstance = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.name -ScriptBlock {Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "DisplayName = '$serviceName'"}
            $row = [pscustomobject]@{
                AppName = $appName
                Server  = $computer.name
                Service = $serviceName
                State   = if($serviceInstance.State -eq 'Running'){$running}else{$stopped}
            }
            $servicesReport += $row
        }
    }

    # Here you could export your $servicesReport to CSV or HTML with Export-Csv or ConvertTo-Html |Out-File
}
```

Comment: Please do not read XML files like this. `[xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)` This looks as easy and logical as it is wrong. `Get-Content` has no idea what character encoding the file is in and you don't specify it anywhere. This is the equivalent of finger crossing. In the best case you get an error. In the more likely case, your data silently breaks. XML parsers have an elaborate mechanism to detect file encoding. Don't circumvent that - use it. `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load($_.FullName)` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: This is great advise, thank you very much. Just another small query. When I run the code, everything works perfectly. However the State always returns as ERROR. Thanks again for your help.